# quick "preview" of incoming multipart request

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to implement a REST service (or even a single Servlet) that will allow me to get a quick "preview" of incoming file (multipart request with a single file in it).

The idea is to parse and store in DB few first lines of potentially huge file coming into the service.

Problem I face is that Spring @RestController (on Tomcat) is run after the whole request is received by a server and MultipartFile is already stored on filesystem.

I managed to implement something that is working with pure Servlet implementation (reading multipart request directly from HttpServletRequest) but... then I need to do all the multipart parsing stuff manually. I tried with commons fileupload (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) but it also caches files on file system, so when I call:

```
        List<FileItem> uploads = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
```

all freezes util whole file is uploaded on server.

Any suggestions how to deal with this - preferably on Tomcat and with @RestController if it is at all possible.

Comment: Please let me know if you are satisfied with my answer, or if not I'd be curious what's wrong with it.

Comment: It looks good @Z4, thanks. I didn't test it (so I don't know for sure), because we choose to implement it in a slightly different way, by splitting file in a smaller chunks (http://resumablejs.com) as it allows for greater scalability and AWS S3 also supports it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you were on the right track with commons-fileupload. You just need to use the ["streaming" API](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html). Something similar should work:

```
@RestController
public class ARestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = Routes.A_ROUTE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> processMultiPart(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
            final FileItemIterator itemIterator = upload.getItemIterator(request);

            while (itemIterator.hasNext()) {
                final FileItemStream fileItemStream = itemIterator.next();
                if (!fileItemStream.isFormField()) {
                    try (InputStream inputStream = fileItemStream.openStream()) {
                        // process the stream the way you want
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This way you could read the parts as stream, use whatever you need from them, and discard the rest. There won't be anything stored on the FS.